# csv.writer.writerow with a comma in a field not writing correctly

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I am pulling data from a website and saving it to CSV in Python.  Works most of the time except when a specific field in one of the rows occasionally is in the thousands and the vendor includes a comma in the field.  No matter how I use writer.writerow() I cant seem to exclude this comma from being interpreted as the delimeter EVEN though the vendor enclosed the specific field in double quotes when the comma appears.

```
# Obtain the data from the website
downloadresponse = s.post(downloadurl, data=downloaddata,headers=postheaders, cookies=loginresponse.cookies)
print("Download response status =", downloadresponse.status_code)
print("Downloading " +filename+" now.")

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter =',',escapechar='\\' ,quotechar ='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, doublequote=True)
    for line in downloadresponse.iter_lines():
        print("Raw Line =", line)
        print("UTF Line =", line.decode('utf-8'))
        print("UTF & Split Line =", line.decode('utf-8').split(','))
        writer.writerow(line.decode('utf-8').split(','))
```

Produces this output for the problematic row in the CSV.

```
Download response status = 200 
Download response reason = OK 
Downloading /Users/someone/Documents/@Investing/UOA-Workspace/data/uoa-eod-02-04-2021.csv now.

DEBUG-Raw Line = b'AMC,7.31,Call,2,02/05/21,1,5.25,5.33,5.4,5.3,739,283,2.61,"1,246.65%","15:10 ET"' \
DEBUG-UTF Line = AMC,7.31,Call,2,02/05/21,1,5.25,5.33,5.4,5.3,739,283,2.61,"1,246.65%","15:10 ET" \
DEBUG-UTF & Split Line = ['AMC', '7.31', 'Call', '2', '02/05/21', '1', '5.25', '5.33', '5.4', '5.3', '739', '283', '2.61', '"1', '246.65%"', '"15:10 ET"']
```

So the field  "1,246.65%" in the raw LINE is being split on the comma into two fields '"1', '246.65%"' even though it's contained in double quotes. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `str.split()` doesn't care about quotes. Why do you expect that it should?

Comment: `line` looks properly formatted with respect to quotes. why not just write to a file like string, not using csv module?

Comment: When asking question like this you should provide a [mre] that others can run (instead of trying to "see" the problem in your code).

Comment: @PranavHosangadi -  I didnt see any other way to get the fields split into separate columns in my CSV.

Comment: @buran - I tried that but when I omit the .split(','). I  end up with every character in the line in a different field or column in my CSV.

Comment: I said "without using csv module"

Comment: ahhh ok not sure how I missed that but it makes sense.

Comment: Thats embarrassing - Thanks @buran.   It works as you said with just f.write(downloadresponse.text) without CSV writer.  If you want to answer I can mark correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can write directly, without using `csv` module. Line looks properly quoted.
Something like

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(downloadresponse.text)
```

This may need some tweaks. e.g. in case of streaming response you may need to write line by line.

Answer (score 0):

For others, @buran provided the answer. I assumed I needed csv.writer but apparently because the API response was already well formatted I just needed to write the response.text to a file and it was formatted perfectly. Updated Code:

```
# Obtain the data from the website
downloadresponse = s.post(downloadurl, data=downloaddata,headers=postheaders, cookies=loginresponse.cookies)
print("Download response status =", downloadresponse.status_code)
print("Downloading " +filename+" now.")

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(downloadresponse.text)
    f.close()
```

Comment: no need of `f.close()` - the `with` context manager takes care to close the file for you.